# What Excel formula can I use to calculate the 2nd Monday of a given month?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

What Excel formula can I use to calculate the second Monday of a given month?

You can assume I have a cell containing the first day of the month to work with.

In the interests of other users, can you please also explain how to alter the formula to get the 1st, 3rd or 4th Monday of the month too, and other days of the week too. eg the third Friday of the Monday...

Comment: I wanted a formula to compute the second Wednesday of the current month and year to use to automatically add the date of the meeting to a sign in sheet for a monthly meeting. I created the formula below. `=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1+7*2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),8-4))`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's something I found with a quick search:

> Generically you can get the nth xday of the month with this formula

```
=DATE(B2,A2,1+7*n)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-xday))
```

> where year is in B2 and month (as a number 1 to 12) is in A2, and where xday is a number representing the day of the week (1 = Sun through to 7 = Sat), so for 1st Saturday that becomes

```
=DATE(B2,A2,1+7*1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-7))
```

> or for 4th Thursday

```
=DATE(B2,A2,1+7*4)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-5))
```

So, if I'm reading this properly, the 2<sup>nd</sup> Monday of the month is

```
=DATE(B2,A2,1+7*2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,A2,8-2))
```

*([credit where credit is due](http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/398194-calculating-the-date-of-the-nth-specific-day-of-the-month.html#post1426804))*

Comment: It works perfectly, as far as I can tell! Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

=IF((WEEKDAY(A1) > 3),(A1+(17-WEEKDAY(A1))),(A1+(10-WEEKDAY(A1))))

A1 is first day of month

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: No need for any explanation - **it flat-out doesn't work**!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work correctly either.  I came up with a super complicated (my idiom) way that does appear to work.

> A2 = Month
>   B2 = year
>   C2 = Day of week (1 - 7, 1 = Sunday)
>   D2 = "number" (3 = 3rd xday etc.)

SO 2nd Monday would be A2 = current month, B2 = current year, C2 = 2 (for Monday) and D2 = 2 (for 2nd Monday)

```
F2 = =IF(MONTH(IF((WEEKDAY(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2))))=$C2,(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))+(($D2*7)-7),IF((WEEKDAY(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2))))<$C2,((VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))+($C2-(WEEKDAY(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))))+(($D2*7)-7)),(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))+($C2-(WEEKDAY(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))))+7+(($D2*7)-7))))=A2,IF((WEEKDAY(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2))))=$C2,(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))+(($D2*7)-7),IF((WEEKDAY(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2))))<$C2,((VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))+($C2-(WEEKDAY(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))))+(($D2*7)-7)),(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))+($C2-(WEEKDAY(VALUE(($A2&"/01/"&$B2)))))+7+(($D2*7)-7))),"error")
```

I'm sure there is a much cleaner way to do this (already noticed if I flip one of my IFs around, I can eliminate some replication) plus most of the repeated formulas could be pulled out into separate cells to make the end formula cleaner. But I haven't had a chance to research what other formulas might be available so I'm leaving it as is for now. I also made an even uglier version with error checking and slightly prettier results. But its too complex to post here.